# Splitting value in array that is already in a array

Tags: php

I am trying to split values that are already stored inside of an array everytime a "/" appears...would this work?

php

```
$start = array('hi', 'hello', 'yes/no');
$finish = explode('/', $start);
```

$finish should now look like:

```
$finish = array('hi', 'hello', 'yes', 'no');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It won't work because you are passing an array to `explode`, while it will only accept a string.

However you can do what you need in several ways. The shortest one would be

```
$finish = explode('/', implode('/', $start));
```

Comment: Ingenious :) I was thinking to do an array_walk, but this is so much better.

Answer (score 3):

```
$finish = array();
foreach ($start as $x) {
    $finish = array_merge($finish, explode('/', $x));
}
```